# How to make custom post template in Thesis theme

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-thesis-theme

I'm struggling to use custom post template in thesis. I would like to use different layouts for different posts. There are many tutorials for using custom page template but I can't find ones for posts. I'm new to Thesis so I probably miss something but if someone knows how to or tutorial that mentions about it, please share with me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've been wondering about this too, as have a lot of people apparently. I just added my thoughts in a thread over on the Thesis forum here: http://diythemes.com/forums/customization/12564-custom-post-template-compatible.html

Eager to hear if you come up with anything workable...

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this (that goes against the thesis custom_functions.php file, unfortunately) is to use this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/

Then, create a page called, say, news.php and put this code inside

```
<?php
/*
Template Name Posts: News
*/

/*
Your custom code goes here
*/
```

Then, once you upload this to your thesis folder, it should show up in the post-template dropdown.

?>

Answer (score 0):

Answer #1 in this post might provide you with a way to style posts in Thesis or elsewhere, as long as you're using WP 2.8+: 
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/20/10-useful-wordpress-hacks-for-advanced-themes/